# Reading lines from a list starting with a user-inputted letter?

Tags: python

To note: Some classmates told me that I HAVE to take userInput to create another list based on the userInput. (Eg: Input "g", Creates list with countries that starts with "g".)

This is my current code.

```
countries = []
population = []
str = []
path = "E:\\SCRIPTING\\Countries.txt"
obj = open(path, "r")
allList = obj.readlines()
obj.close()
userI = input("Please input a single letter: ")
if userI.isalpha():
    if len(userI) > 1:
        print("Please enter only a single letter.")
    else:
        print("continue")
elif userI.isdigit():
    int(userI)
    print("Please enter a single letter, not a number.")
else:
    print("Please make sure that you enter a single letter.")
```

So far from what I have I know that it's reading my .txt file, and displaying different errors/messages when incorrect inputs are given.
(Program to be put under the else: print("continue) since its my checkpoint.

The program is made to accept only 1 letter and print all lines which start with that letter.

Comment: Something like: `for line in allList: doSomeCheck`?

Answer (score 1):

You could return a list with a simple test, just before your :

```
print("continue")
```

You could add those lines

```
listToBeDisplayed = [line for line in allList if line.startswith(userI)]
for line in listToBeDisplayed :
    print line
```

Comment: you are unnecessarily looping over the lines twice for something which can be done in a single iteration.

Comment: Agreed, just easier to read, optimisation was not the point. ;)

Comment: Didn't seem to work for me, simply only shows the "continue". :/

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually applying the main logic, you have done the input handling, file opening correctly.

You need:

```
else:
    # Bad variable name, see python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id36
    for line in allList
        if line.startswith(userI):
            print line

elif userI.isdigit():
```

UPDATE:

There is one more change I suggest, after looking at your updated code:

```
# raw_input() instead of input()
userI = raw_input("Please input a single letter: ")
```

Apart from that, I have tested your code and it works provided that there is text data in the file pointed by `path`. Also another note, `startswith` is case sensitive, so make sure you give alphabet in correct case as the text in file.

Comment: it didn't print anything, just a blank line :/

Comment: @tyroneH: Are you sure there are non-blank lines in that file? Share your updated code otherwise.

Comment: countries = []
population = []
str = []
path = "H:\\SCRIPTING\\Countries.txt"
obj = open(path, "r")
allList = obj.readlines()
obj.close()
userI = input("Please input a single letter: ")
if userI.isalpha():
    if len(userI) > 1:
        print("Please enter only a single letter.")
    else:
        for line in allList:
            if line.startswith(userI):
                print (line)
elif userI.isdigit():
    int(userI)
    print("Please enter a single letter, not a number.")
else:
    print("Please make sure that you enter a single letter.")